# Prepare for segue returning nil for indexPathForSelectedRow?

Tags: swift, tableview

I want to pass information from an array from one viewController to another based on what row was selected in my `tableView`.  To do this I have implemented the following functions:

```
func tableView(_ messagesListTableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        messagesListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "individualMessageSegue", sender: self)
        print(indexPath)//returns [0,0]... meaning the first row
    }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "individualMessageSegue" else{return}

        if let indexPath = self.messagesListTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let openedMessageConversation = fullOrderedMessageArray[(indexPath.row)] //cause app to crash because nil value
            let destViewController: IndividualMessageVC = segue.destination as! IndividualMessageVC
            destViewController.messageConvo = openedMessageConversation
        }else{
            print("it was nil")
        }

    }
```

I believe I have everything set up correctly, however despite the print statement from the `didSelectRowAt` always returning a value for the `indexPath` of [0,0] (in the table there is only one section and one row), the print statement in `prepare` always tells me that the `indexPath` is `nil`. If I remove the `if let` conditional, the app will crash because `fullOrderedMessageArray[(indexPath.row)]` contains the nil value. I have no idea why it keeps returning nil for one function while not for the other.

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov doing that gives me the error that the "Method does not override any method from its super class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
func tableView(_ messagesListTableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    messagesListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "individualMessageSegue", sender: indexPath)
    print(indexPath)//returns [0,0]... meaning the first row
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "individualMessageSegue" else{return}

    if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
        let openedMessageConversation = fullOrderedMessageArray[(indexPath.row)] 
        let destViewController: IndividualMessageVC = segue.destination as! IndividualMessageVC
        destViewController.messageConvo = openedMessageConversation
    }else{
        print("it was nil")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit here is

```
messagesListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

By this line you have asked your tableview to deselect the selected row.
After this statement there is no row selected hence, when you ask the table view to return the selected row it gives nil

```
self.messagesListTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow // will be nil
```

Though, Bapu has provided a solution to your problem, but this is the answer to your question, "Prepare for segue returning nil for indexPathForSelectedRow?"

Just comment out the `messagesListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` and your old code will work as expected.